# Regular expression to detect few non characters

Tags: php, regex

How do i do a regular expression that will allow everything except !@$%^&*()_+={}[]|:";'<>,.?/ (If i need to detect more than these can I simply add them into the regexp later?)

I intend using this to check if these character are present in postal addresses a user submits. So if they were there, I could reject the address.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're filtering out all of the special characters you can think of. Are you sure you don't want to go with a whitelist (allow only a specified set of characters) instead?

Comment: Among the special characters, i'd like to allow - #

Comment: Also, you should consider whether you really need to ban these characters.  After all, someone could eventually have an address with one of the excluded characters.  You may only need to use prepared statements for databases and escape (e.g. with `htmlspecialchars`) for output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include allowed characters instead of excluding almost everything :

```
[\w+-]*
```

---

But if you want to really exclude those chars :

```
[^!@$%^&*()_+={}\[\]|\:";'<>,.?/]*
```

---

**Resources :**

- [regular-expressions.info - Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: So if I wanted to allow or disallow a few characters, i could simply add or remove them from the expression. Right?

Comment: Yes, to allow them, add them to the first expression. If you want to remove use the second one.